# Controlling Windows Service (Start, Stop and more..) with self hosted NancyFX web interface

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, nancy, self-hosting

My goal is to create a simple web interface for a windows service that will allow me to interact with the service using a web browser.

By interaction I mean that by pressing a button in an html page I will be able to call `Stop()` method defined inside the service class. (or any other methods available)

I have a class that is going to be hosted inside a ServiceHost, running as a Windows Service.
The hierarchy is the following:

```
public interface IMyServiceInterface
{
        string Name { get; set; }
        void Stop();
}

public class MyServiceBase : IMyServiceInterface
{
  string sName;
  public string Name
  {
    get {return sName; }
    set {sName = value;}
  }

  public virtual void Stop() {}
}

public class dbSynchronizer : MyServiceBase 
{
   public dbSynchronizer()
   {
      this.Name = "dbSynchronizer_01";
   }

   public override void Stop()
   {
      base.Stop();
    }
}
```

The code for starting the hosts:

File: **Program.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun; 
   ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
   {
     new dbSynchronizerService()
   };
   ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

File: **dbSynchronizerService.cs**

```
public partial class dbSynchronizerService : ServiceBase
{    
   NancyHost nancyHost;
   dbSynchronizer  dbSynchronizerService;

   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
   {

      dbSynchronizerInstance = new dbSyncronizerLib.dbSynchronizer();

      CustomBootstrapper _custBootStrapper = new CustomBootstrapper();
      nancyHost = new Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost(new                 Uri("http://localhost:9664"), _custBootStrapper);                

      if (nancyHost != null)
          nancyHost.Start();

      sHost = new ServiceHost(dbSynchronizerInstance);
      sHost.Open();           
     }    
}
```

Inside the MainModule defined for Nancy I need to get access to the current isntance of dbSynchronizer class (currently being executed inside the service host) to gain access to methods and properties.
To begin with, I just want a simple view that will display the name of the service like below:

File: **MainModule.cs**:

```
public class MainModule : NancyModule
    {
        public IMyServiceInterface _myService;

        public MainModule(IMyServiceInterface _service)
        {
            _myService= _service;

            Get["/"] = x =>
            {

                var model = new ConfigStatusModel
                {
                    Message = String.IsNullOrEmpty(_service.Name) ? "Cannot get service name" : _service.Name
                };

                return View["index.html", model];
            };
        }
    }
```

After this step, I would also like to make some POST to some other modules to invoke methods such as `Stop()` or any other methods that are supposed to be triggered by human intervention: `DoSyncDb(), CleanTable().`

At this point, when running the service and requesting the `http://localhost:9664/` I get the "Cannot get service name" value in the model attached to the view.

Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong or point me to a working sample? Or maybe tell me how can what I described above be achieved properly.

Thank you.